# How to get data from measurement by group by column_name and max time?

Tags: influxdb

How to get data from measurement by group by column_name and max time?

Here is query I am trying to execute

**select cpu_number from vm_details where ro_id='8564a08b-9208-45bf-9758-7d64fe1f91a3' group by entity_uuid;**

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT mt.*,     
FROM MyTable mt INNER JOIN
    (
        SELECT ID, MIN(Record_Date) MinDate
        FROM MyTable
        GROUP BY ID
    ) t ON mt.ID = t.ID AND mt.Record_Date = t.MinDate
```

This gets the minimum date per ID, and then gets the values based on those values. The only time you would have duplicates is if there are duplicate minimum record_dates for the same ID.